# How to include SharpPcap framework in C# vscode

Tags: c#, networking, frameworks, packet

So I am trying to create a project using SharpPcap to collect the packets coming in and out of my wifi and find any suspicious ones. Its a school project that I had 100% freedom to do whatever I want.

So I am using vscode and I am coding it on my Mac. I downloaded LibPcap using home-brew which it said I need to do.

I created a project directory and downloaded SharpPcap and have the folder in my project directory. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to include it in my C# file to even use it.

This is my first time using an external framework so I am kind of clueless. I haven't found anything online that has helped me.

```
    using PacketDotNet;

ushort tcpSourcePort = 123;
ushort tcpDestinationPort = 321;
var tcpPacket = new TcpPacket(tcpSourcePort, tcpDestinationPort);

var ipSourceAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
var ipDestinationAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2");
var ipPacket = new IPv4Packet(ipSourceAddress, ipDestinationAddress);

var sourceHwAddress = "90-90-90-90-90-90";
var ethernetSourceHwAddress = System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress.Parse(sourceHwAddress);
var destinationHwAddress = "80-80-80-80-80-80";
var ethernetDestinationHwAddress = System.Net.NetworkInformation.PhysicalAddress.Parse(destinationHwAddress);

// NOTE: using EthernetPacketType.None to illustrate that the Ethernet
//       protocol type is updated based on the packet payload that is
//       assigned to that particular Ethernet packet
var ethernetPacket = new EthernetPacket(ethernetSourceHwAddress,
    ethernetDestinationHwAddress,
    EthernetPacketType.None);

// Now stitch all of the packets together
ipPacket.PayloadPacket = tcpPacket;
ethernetPacket.PayloadPacket = ipPacket;

// and print out the packet to see that it looks just like we wanted it to
Console.WriteLine(ethernetPacket.ToString());

// to retrieve the bytes that represent this newly created EthernetPacket use the Bytes property
byte[] packetBytes = ethernetPacket.Bytes;
```

This code is in the documentation for SharpPcap. I can't figure out how to link the directory to my file I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to build and run your application with `SharpPcap` library (not debugging that library), you can use [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpPcap) to manage that library.

Here is what `.csproj` file looks like (here I choose version 5.3.0, while you can choose any version of `SharpPcap` based on your requirements):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="SharpPcap" Version="5.3.0" />
        </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Just a side note, you need to change the line below to make it compile and run.

```
var ethernetPacket = new EthernetPacket(ethernetSourceHwAddress,
    ethernetDestinationHwAddress,
    EthernetType.None); // Not EthernetPacketType.None
```